# Array List storing and checking issue

Tags: java, arraylist

I am currently developing a program that finds the first consonant in a word. Here is the code from the main class:

```
            consonantLoop = 0;
            while(!consonantFound) {
                currentLetter = characters.get(consonantLoop);
                for(int x = 0; x < consonants.size(); x++) {
                     if(currentLetter == consonants.get(x)) {
                         consonantFound = true;
                         System.out.println("The first constanent in the word is " + consonants.get(x).toString());
                     } else {
                         consonantLoop++;
                     }
                }
            }
```

The varible `consonantLoop` is what I use to identify the letter of the word that I am checking if it is a vowel. `consonantFound` is a boolean which states whether the first consonant has been found. `currentLetter` is a char to define which letter I am currently checking. `characters` is the arraylist where my characters are stored. `consonants` is the array in which the consonants are stored. However, when I run the code and the seconds letter is a consonant, it gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 42, Size: 3
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at testing.Main.main(Main.java:44)
```

Line 44 is `currentLetter = characters.get(consonantLoop);`

With some help thanks to @RajenRaiyare I have been able to edit my code so I don't get any more errors:

```
consonantLoop = 0;
while(!consonantFound) {
                try {
                    currentLetter = characters.get(consonantLoop);
                    for(int x = 0; x < consonants.size(); x++) {
                        if(currentLetter == consonants.get(x)) {
                            consonantFound = true;
                            System.out.println("The first consonant in the word is " + consonants.get(x).toString());
                        } else {
                            consonantLoop++;
                }
            }
        } catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException  e) {
            break;
        }
    }
```

However now after typing the in the word the program just terminates. What is the problem?

Comment: Were you aware that ArrayLists have a `contains` method?

Comment: But to be honest, I don't really see how that will help me...

Comment: You don't need to loop through `consonants` manually. You can check `if (consonants.contains(currentLetter))`, letting `contains` perform the loop for you.

Comment: Sorry, I'm being a bit stupid here, but could you put the whole code in an answer please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has two primary problems. First, you aren't stopping when you hit the end of the list (or in your new version, you're using a very strange way to do so). Second, you're incrementing `consonantLoop` once for *every* consonant `currentLetter` isn't. You only want to do that once for each value of `currentLetter`. The easiest way to increment like that is with a `for` loop instead of a `while`:

```
for (int consonantLoop = 0; consonantLoop < characters.size() && !consonantFound;
        consonantLoop++) {
    ...
}
```

Using a loop counter at all is unnecessary complication, though. A for-each loop is a cleaner way to iterate over the contents of `characters`. While we're at it, we can replace the clunky inner loop with a call to the `contains` method:

```
for (Character c : characters) {
    if (consonants.contains(c)) {
        System.out.println("First consonant: " + c);
        break;
    }
}
```

The `break` ends the loop, since we can't use a `consonantFound` flag with a for-each loop.

Answer (score 2):

Currently what you are doing is you are simply going on incrementing constantLoop counter but not checking whether it is lesser than the size of the arraylist from which you are getting the records. So if value of constantLoop is equal to size of arraylist means it will give IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Two method to solve this

1.

```
catch IndexOutOfBoundsException and do break from it.
```

2.

```
if (constantLoop < characters.size()) {
currentLetter = characters.get(constantLoop);
}else{
break;
}
```

Comment: I tried method one, and it worked, no more errors, but now after typing in my word the program just terminates.

Comment: for that you need to share that code. without that we can not know what is there in activity and how it is being handled.

Comment: @tomtomy8 that could needs to be edited into your question; not posted as a comment.

Comment: A question for you, @GeorgeStocker, whats could?

Comment: @tomtomy8 the code you posted as a comment to this answer.

Comment: I do not see any diff between the code in question and the code you just pasted in comment. so where are you getting the error ?

Answer (score 0):

You have no test to avoid that `consonantLoop` go beyond the size of `characters` if you get a word without any consonant.

You should write your loop :

```
while ((!consonantFound) && (consonantLoop < characters.length())) {
    ...
}
```